# JSON key search in PostgreSQL using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, full-text-search

I have a JSON field `data` that contains following data-

```
{"name":"xx"}
```

I want to perform a full text search on this field using Hibernate. Is there any way I can achieve this? I followed some examples but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried Hibernate native SQL queries?

Comment: I disagree with the close-votes, this is neither overbroad or off-topic. It's entirely sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally Hibernate would have native support for querying inside JSON objects via JPQL/HQL and/or Criteria queries.  That does not appear to be the case at the moment (5.0.1).

It looks like at present you will need to use native queries using one of these methods:

- [Use `EntityManager.createNativeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String)) or one of its variants;
- Define a [`@NamedNativeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html) in your mapping then use `EntityManager.createNamedQuery` to run it; or
- Unwrap the `EntityManager`, unwrapping the `Session` underneath, and use JDBC

If you're using the native Hibernate interfaces not the JPA ones there are Hibernate equivalents to all the above - named native queries in the mapping, creating native queries via the `Session` object, or unwrapping the `Session` to get a `java.sql.Connection`.

In all those cases you'll need to use PostgreSQL-specific operators like `?` and `->>` for querying the json and regular SQL, not JPQL/HQL. See [postgresql json operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). Note that JSON functionality was introduced in 9.3 and enhanced in both 9.4 and 9.5, so check whether your version has the features you need.

For example, you can use `myjsoncolumn ? 'key'` with `jsonb` in 9.4+. With plain `json` types, you'll need to use `(myjsoncolumn -> 'key') IS NULL`. It's important to use `->` not `->>` because `->` returns a json null object for an object like `{"a":null}`, the other returns `NULL`, so you can't tell the difference between `{"a":null}` and `{}`.

Comment: Thanks this is what i wanted to know. I just wanted to make clear that there is no any other way except EntityManager.createNativeQuery. Thanks

Comment: @Justin You can create a named native query in your mapping, then run it later with `createNamedQuery`. That way you can later change the `@NamedNativeQuery` to a plain `@NamedQuery` if/when Hibernate adds JPQL/HQL support for querying within JSON objects. This is probably what I'd do unless I was doing lots of dynamic SQL.